# JPA with Hibernate using Tomcat ..Is it possible?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, tomcat7

I have Tomcat server and I'd like to know, Can I use `JPA` implementation from Hibernate? Is it all rigth? I use Spring , Hibernate, BlazeDs  and Flex4.
I spend a lot of time thinking if I should have to use `JPA` with Hibernate Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure Tomcat works with *any* JPA implementation. In fact there is nothing in the JPA spec that would prevent it, since all JEE standards are supposed to be interoperable

Answer (score 0):

JPA implementation from hibernate works fine with Tomcat 7.
i worked on a similar application which was using Spring MVC web development framework along with JPA from hibernate. intially i was using glassfish but Spring has lot of issues with glassfish. 5/10 times application wouldnt work when i finally switched on to apache tomcat and it worked like cream.
so go ahead with it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA-Hibernate using Spring. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa but JPATemplate is also an option with spring

Comment: or a new one                       http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa.

Comment: Thanks! Now , I'm reading Apress.Spring.Persistence.with.Hibernate.Oct.2010 and it seams to me, a good guide for me as beginner.